# Hide disqus features like rss and email

Tags: function, email, rss, disqus

How can you hide rss & email function on disqus? I don't wan't it to display! Eventually delete the DISQUS logo too? PLEASE HELP!!! if you want this is the link for disqus, http://disqus.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to remember that Disqus isn't just a "comment system", it's a network of users, sites and discussions. We recently hid the RSS option, but the email subscription option and the logo are definitely there to stay.

Disqus is a system that's designed so that users are instantly familiar with it, that doesn't require separate logins, and can aggregate content to drive traffic. If customizations are more important, a different solution might be better.